# IIS appcmd on Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, iis-7, appcmd

For IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2003, any tools like appcmd for IIS 7.0 with Windows Server 2008? I did not find such command on Windows Server 2003.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: IIS 7.0 on Windows Server 2003? Are you sure?

Comment: heh, I completely missed that. I'm guessing that was just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several command-line tools for IIS6.

[Start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525006.aspx) and then come back with more specific questions.

Comment: I am using IIS 7.0 (SharePoint installed) on Windows Server 2003. Any tools for IIS 7.0 Windows Server 2003? I find no appcmd available?

Comment: @George2: IIS 7 on Windows Server 2003? I don't think that's possible. IIS 7 is only available on Windows Server 2008 platforms as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, you can't run IIS7 on Windows Server 2003. I didn't even notice that in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

True, IIS 7 is for more recent Windows versions than 2003. I'm pretty sure you are actually running IIS 6 if it's Server 2003. Which brings us to the original question, "any tools like appcmd" in this context? - which none of the other answers have addressed.

In that environment appcmd doesn't exist. It's also not listed in the IIS command-line tools in another answer on this page. But I am guessing you want to assign multiple web sites to the same secure wildcard certificate, differentiating by site name (a.k.a. SNI) which appcmd does.

In the older system that function is performed by adsutil.vbs. Here are the commands you need:

```
cd C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts
cscript.exe adsutil.vbs set /w3svc/<site_id>/SecureBindings ":443:<site_url>"
```

where  is the internal IIS numeric ID for this site, and  is the name of the site, like "google.com". You can see the site ID from the IIS main dialog box; click Web Sites on the left, and all the sites and their IDs show up on the right.

If you already have the same secure cert assigned to another site on the server, IIS will not permit the 2nd site to start up until you issue the above command. Then you can go and start the 2nd site.

A background explanation and more detailed general instructions (with screen shot) are here: https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/configure-iis-host-headers.htm .

I've used this procedure numerous time in the last 15 years or so - most recently, just yesterday.